# Data type mismatch in criteria expression Oledb Access database

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm getting the error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

When using this code. And using Access database.

```
OleDbConnection bab = new OleDbConnection();

bab.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\sdega\OneDrive\school\Werknemersdata.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

bab.Open();
try
{                  
    OleDbCommand kaas = new OleDbCommand();

    kaas.Connection = bab;
    kaas.CommandText = "insert into Werknemersdata (Naam, Adres, Postcode, Woonplaats, Salaris) values ('" + txtNaam.Text + "', '" + txtAdress.Text + "', '" + txtpostcode1.Text + " " +txtpostcode2.Text + "', '" + txtwoonplaats.Text + "', '" + txtsalaris.Text + "')  ";
    kaas.ExecuteNonQuery(); // this is where it goes wrong

    txtStatus.BackColor = Color.Green;

    MessageBox.Show("data saved");

    bab.Close();

}
catch (Exception ghakbal)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + ghakbal);
}
```

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. Check this link to know How does accepting an answer work:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

You missed one `'` after `'" + txtpostcode1.Text + "` and one before `" +txtpostcode2.Text + "'` and also one `,` between them. It should be like this:

```
'" + txtpostcode1.Text + "' , '" +txtpostcode2.Text + "',
```

Also I strongly recommend that you always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Like this:

```
kaas.CommandText = "insert into Werknemersdata (Naam, Adres, Postcode, Woonplaats, Salaris) values (?, ? ,.....");
kaas.Parameters.AddWithValue("Naam", txtNaam.Text);
kaas.Parameters.AddWithValue("Adres", txtAdress.Text);
//And other parameters...
```

Also It would be better to specify the type directly and use the `Value` property. Read more [here](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).